# JS. Неожиданный результат при битовом ИЛИ двух чисел

Tags: javascript, node.js, типы-данных, битовые-операции

```
var a = 0x81000000; //   2164260864
var b = 0x00FFFFFF; //   16777215
var c = 0x81FFFFFF; //   2181038079
var d = a | b; //        -2113929217

var test = c == d; //    false
```

**Собственно вопрос:**
Как можно объяснить подобное поведение JS и в каком случае выражение `d == c` будет истинно, при **A>=0x80000000**?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/bitwise-operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Равенства не будет никогда потому что `0x81FFFFFF` не принадлежит диапазону `[-2147483648, 2147483647]`.

Все битовые операции в JavaScript приводят свои аргументы  и результаты к 32-хбитовым целым числам со знаком. Например, значение `0x81000000` не помещается в диапазон и будет приведено. Результат приведения `-2130706432`:

> ```
> $ node
> > let a = 0x81000000;
> undefined
> > a
> 2164260864
> > a | 0
> -2130706432
> ```

Чтобы добиться равенства приведите обе стороны:

> ```
> > (0x81FFFFFF | 0) === (0x81000000 | 0x00FFFFFF)
> true
> ```